# Problem understanding response from MapServer WCS

Tags: mapserver, wcs

I can't understand what I am doing wrong with my WCS request.

When submitting this request from a browser the result is an output called  mapserv.

http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/usr/local/mapserver_work/wcs1.map&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&coverage=jeo&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=25.670,35.813,44.824,42.106&WIDTH=1600&HEIGHT=1066&FORMAT=GTiff&

Comment: I would save the result on a disk, rename it into "wcs.tif" or anything and check if it after all happens to be a valid tiff file.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is an error response from MapServer.  There is something wrong with your request and MapServer is sending an error message, the name of the error file is `mapserv` it is a file of type `application/vnd.ogc.se_xml`, not a copy of the MapServer executable.  If you open the file in a text editor you will see what the error is..

Guesses might be:

`FORMAT=GTiff&` format is not supported in your service what if you use:
`format=image/tiff`

`CRS=EPSG:4326&` the CRS is incorrectly attributed, what if you use: `crs=urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84`